How to deal with precision differences in Swift Date and Firestore Timestamp.dateValue()
Consider the following code:
let timestamp = Timestamp(seconds: 171475088, nanoseconds: 330370000)
                let dateValue = timestamp.dateValue()
                let newTimeStamp = Timestamp(date: timestamp.dateValue())
                let newDateValue = newTimeStamp.dateValue()

                print("timestamp: \(timestamp)")
                print("dateValue: \(dateValue)")
                print("newTimeStamp: \(newTimeStamp)")
                print("newDateValue: \(newDateValue)")

This prints:
timestamp: <FIRTimestamp: seconds=171475088 nanoseconds=330370000>
dateValue: 1975-06-08 15:58:08 +0000
newTimeStamp: <FIRTimestamp: seconds=171475088 nanoseconds=330369949>
newDateValue: 1975-06-08 15:58:08 +0000

I am loosing 51 nanoseconds. This may not seem like a lot but it affects how we compare dates in queries.
The specific use case is I am trying to store a lastModifiedDate on a document every time I make a change. I can create a timestamp from a date but the problem is I want to store this date in UserDefaults so that next time I launch my app I can retrieve it and only fetch newer documents. I cannot store timestamps in UserDefaults. When I do store the Swift Date in user defaults and get it later and turn it back into a timestamp for the isGreaterThan comparison, it is different and the comparison fails.   So outside of creating a string representation of the timestamp does anyone have any other suggestions?

A Firestore timestamp has a granularity that measure down to nanoseconds (as you can see from the data).  A Swift Date returned by dateValue() does not have such a small granularity.  In fact, if you click through to that link to the API docs, it says:

This may lose precision.

That's exactly what's happening here - you've lost precision due to the fact that a Swift Date does not have the same granularity as a Firestore Timestamp.
The only way you can work around this is to store the actual values of the timestamp (both seconds and nanoseconds, or some other value that combines them without losing precision (such as a string where both numbers have been zero-padded and concatenated so they compare numerically), then make comparisons with other timestamp with those two values in the future.
